# Tomcat elasticity with Tomcat and Microsoft Azure

Tags: tomcat, azure, cloud

I'm new to the Microsoft Azure / Cloud environments and have a question of elasticity.  I want to know if there are specific guidelines I need to conform to in order get automated scale in/out from a resource perspective.  So as the traffic for my web application ramps up/down, new resources are allocated and deallocated automatically.  Are there specific API's I need to hook into?  Is there specific way to deploy my application (i think of AWS Beanstalk)...., is there a specific virtual machine image I have to leverage (not because it makes creating a Tomcat server simpler, but because it take into account this capacity mgmt into account)?

I have the feeling there is something more I need to do than just spin up a windows server and open a web server and everything works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that Azure is an IaaS. That is, it provides you with the infrastructure to run your apps, and it speaks in terms of machines and hardware. I am not sure application based metric auto scaling is possible, and even if it is, my guess is that its pretty complicated.

Have you looked at this page? 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-scale-a-cloud-service/

There is a better way of approaching this issue. What you need is a PaaS layer that sits on top of azure and does all that auto scaling, failover, monitoring stuff for you. since its a PaaS, it speaks in terms of applications and services, which is what you need. you want to scale tomcat, not the server.

There is an open source tool that does exactly that and integrates easily with azure (as well as other cloud providers).
Its called Cloudify,and here is a small tumblr post i wrote about deploying tomcat with it.

http://cloudifysource.tumblr.com/post/36064925458/using-azure-iaas-with-cloudify

Disclaimer, i work for [GigaSpaces](http://www.gigaspaces.com/), developing the Cloudify product line.